# Quoting filenames in multi-step xargs bash pipeline

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, xargs

I am creating a bash pipeline where I want to find files that contain specific text and then do something with only those files.  I can successfully get the list of files using the `find`/`xargs` pairing:

```bash
$ find .  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l mysearchtext
./dir1/my file.txt
./thefile.pdf
```

Now that I have the files that match, I want to perform another operation on *those files only*, something like this:

```bash
$ find .  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l mysearchtext | xargs open
```

This will fail, as the second `xargs` call interprets `./dir1/my file.txt` as two files.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this last part of the pipeline?

Comment: Does your version of `grep` support `--null`? If it does, you should be able to use that and `xargs -0 open`.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -q mysearchtext {} \; -exec open {} +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your version of `grep` supports the `--null` option (which makes it use the null character as a delimiter after filenames, very like `find ... -print0`), you can use that:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l --null mysearchtext | xargs -0 open
```

As jhnc points out in a comment, it's also possible to use `grep -q` as a test with `find`'s `-exec` primary (and you can also replace the `-print0 | xargs -0` with `-exec ... +`):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q mysearchtext {} \; -print0  | xargs -0 open
```

Since that's all within the `find` test expression, you can also replace the `-print0 | xargs -0` with `-exec ... +`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q mysearchtext {} \; -exec open {} +
```

Note the difference between `-exec ... \;`, which runs the command separately for each file and can be used as a test, and `-exec ... +` which runs the command on batches of files (like `xargs`), and therefore cannot be used to test individual files.